# How to change vertical spacing between lines in text environment, but NOT between lines in an equation type environment

Tags: spacing, text, line

I know there is the setspace package with onehalfspacing etc, but when I use that command (even worse for doublespacing), it changes the space between EVERYTHING, equations included, and I end up with ridiculous amounts of whitespace at the top and bottom of pages.

How can I only change spacing between lines of text without affecting equation spacing in other environments?

Thanks!

EDIT: Some sample code. I would like to have independent control of spacing between lines of text and lines of equations.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}

The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog, who couldn't even be bothered to learn to FOIL, a technique that even the densest puppies can usually master. The dog under consideration can't even do this:
\begin{eqnarray}
(x+1)(x+2) &=& x^2+2x+x+2\nonumber\\
&=& x^2+3x+2.\nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
Tell me, what do you make of that? Is there any hope for this uninspired pooch? I think not!

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing...

Comment: In particular, do tell us if (a) you load the `setspace` package with the option `nodisplayskipstretch` and/or (b) you leave blank lines before an `equation`, `gather`, `align`, etc environment.

Comment: @Mico nodisplayskipstretch helps, but even with that, when I do onehalfspacing, I get comically large gaps between text and the next section heading. \allowdisplaybreaks doesn't improve it very much.

Comment: @bananaspace -- `\allowdisplaybreaks` is meant for something entirely different.  But a blank line before the `amsmath` display environments *does* add extra, unwanted space, namely a `\parskip`.  Just learn to think of the display as a continuation of the paragraph that precedes it.

Comment: @barberabeeton I'm in the habit of not adding lines. My experience is onehalfspacing does terrible things for page layout, like sporadic huge gaps between text and following section headings. I would like some systematic way to avoid that.